# ICAL Wrong date in outlook (windows and android) but good in Google Calendar and Iphone ical

Tags: android, outlook, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

Hi There im busy with an i cal calendar.
But he display wrong date:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:TEST EVENT!
UID:140
STATUS:CONFIRMED
DTSTAMP;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20170610T220000Z
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20170610T220000Z
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20170610T220000Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20170608T064314Z
LOCATION:STREET 1 1111 AA CITY
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

This sould be date: 11/06/2017 22:00 (Day time Amsterdam)
In Outlook is the date: 11/06/2017 00:00 (Day time Amsterdam)

This is the rest of my code:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:PUBLISH
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//2017/TEST CALENDAR//EN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Amsterdam
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20151025T020000
RDATE:20160327T030000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
TZNAME:Europe/Amsterdam CET
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20161030T020000
RDATE:20170326T030000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
TZNAME:Europe/Amsterdam CET
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20150601T073000
RDATE:20151025T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
TZNAME:Europe/Amsterdam CEST
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20160327T030000
RDATE:20161030T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
TZNAME:Europe/Amsterdam CEST
END:DAYLIGHT
```

I hope someone can help me out!
Thanks alot!

My php code which generate the Ical is below:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
$querystr ="
SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta 
WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
AND ( $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'confirmed'
OR $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'pending'
)
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC";
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
?>
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/Calendar");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=TESTAGENDA.ics");
// the iCal date format. Note the Z on the end indicates a UTC timestamp.
define('DATE_ICAL', 'Ymd\THis\Z');
// max line length is 75 chars. New line is \\n
$output = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
$output .= "METHOD:PUBLISH\r\n";
$output .= "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
$output .= "PRODID:-//2017/TEST AGENDA//EN\r\n";

$output .= "BEGIN:VTIMEZONE\r\n";
$output .= "TZID:Europe/Amsterdam\r\n";
$output .= "BEGIN:STANDARD\r\n";
$output .= "DTSTART:20151025T020000\r\n";
$output .= "RDATE:20160327T030000\r\n";
$output .= "TZOFFSETFROM:+0200\r\n";
$output .= "TZOFFSETTO:+0100\r\n";
$output .= "TZNAME:Europe/Amsterdam CET\r\n";
$output .= "END:STANDARD\r\n";
$output .= "BEGIN:STANDARD\r\n";
$output .= "DTSTART:20161030T020000\r\n";
$output .= "RDATE:20170326T030000\r\n";
$output .= "TZOFFSETFROM:+0200\r\n";
$output .= "TZOFFSETTO:+0100\r\n";
$output .= "TZNAME:Europe/Amsterdam CET\r\n";
$output .= "END:STANDARD\r\n";
$output .= "BEGIN:DAYLIGHT\r\n";
$output .= "DTSTART:20150601T073000\r\n";
$output .= "RDATE:20151025T020000\r\n";
$output .= "TZOFFSETFROM:+0100\r\n";
$output .= "TZOFFSETTO:+0200\r\n";
$output .= "TZNAME:Europe/Amsterdam CEST\r\n";
$output .= "END:DAYLIGHT\r\n";
$output .= "BEGIN:DAYLIGHT\r\n";
$output .= "DTSTART:20160327T030000\r\n";
$output .= "RDATE:20161030T020000\r\n";
$output .= "TZOFFSETFROM:+0100\r\n";
$output .= "TZOFFSETTO:+0200\r\n";
$output .= "TZNAME:Europe/Amsterdam CEST\r\n";
$output .= "END:DAYLIGHT\r\n";
$output .= "END:VTIMEZONE\r\n";
?>
<?php if ($pageposts){ ?>
<?php global $post; ?>
<?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
<?php $postmeta_reservering = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'rtb', true );
if ( ! empty( $postmeta_reservering ) ) {
    $aantalpersonen = $postmeta_reservering['party'];
    $emailadres = $postmeta_reservering['email'];
    $telefoonnr = $postmeta_reservering['phone'];
    $ipadres = $postmeta_reservering['ip'];
}
?>
<?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
<?php if($post->post_status == 'confirmed'){$poststatus = 'CONFIRMED';}else{$poststatus = 'IN-PROCESS';}
$output .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n";
$output .= "SUMMARY:".$post->post_title." Tel.:".$telefoonnr." (".$aantalpersonen." pers.)\r\n";
$output .= "UID:".$post->ID."\r\n";
$output .= "STATUS:".$poststatus."\r\n";
$output .= "DTSTAMP;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:".date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime($post->post_date))."\r\n";
$output .= "DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:".date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime($post->post_date))."\r\n";
$output .= "DTEND;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:".date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime($post->post_date))."\r\n";
$output .= "LAST-MODIFIED:".date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime($post->post_modified))."\r\n";
$output .= "LOCATION:STREET 01 1111 AA CITY\r\n";
$output .= "END:VEVENT\r\n";?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php
// close calendar
$output .= "END:VCALENDAR";
// loop over events
echo $output;
?>
<?php }else{ ?>
    <span>No event!</span>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a datetime format with timezone but in the meantime, you are suffixing those with a Z which indicates zulu/UTC time. So different clients will pick up a different interpretation.

Just remove the final Z from DTSTART and DTEND fields. DTSTAMP is expressed in zulu time only. Finally, your DTEND is equal to your DTSTART which is not legal (must be later in time, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.2.2 )

```
DTSTAMP:20170610T220000Z
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20170610T220000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20170610T230000
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same issue, finally i solved using below method, hope this will help you.

Pass your date to below method, to get global GMT time

```
public static Date cvtToGMT(Date myDate){
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    Date cvtDate = new Date( myDate.getTime() - timeZone.getRawOffset());
    if(timeZone.inDaylightTime(cvtDate)){
        Date dstDate = new Date(cvtDate.getTime() - timeZone.getDSTSavings());
        if ( timeZone.inDaylightTime( dstDate )){
            cvtDate = dstDate;
        }
    }
    return cvtDate;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer but need i to put this on top of my PHP file wich make's the ical? Can is send you my whole code?

Comment: In which language you are implementing ical? After getting date we have to convert it to GMT format.

Comment: With wordpress / PHP see above i added the PHP code

Comment: The above code posted which is in java. In your language you have to convert the date(given in ical) to global format.